# Cypress API native assertion gets error in eslint

Tags: cypress, eslint

So I have eslint rules (for typescript project) for whole project, which I can't change - I'm extending them to e2e folder with Cypress (and here I override them if needed), also with `plugin:cypress/recommended` eslint rules. But now I'm struggling with errors in assertions. For example I have:

```js
cy.get("button")
      .should((button) => {
        expect(button).to.be.enabled;
      })
      .click();
```

And on assertion I get `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions`. I don't want to disable this rule for each line, or for whole project, because somewhere else I can forget/or something to do unused expression. How to resolve this only for assertions in Cypress? In eslint config where I have extension should I add something only for that?

Comment: How about you just use `cy.get("button").should('be.enabled').click()` ?

Comment: @AlapanDas what about case with many assertions where using callback function is the best instead of `.and()`?

Comment: Hi TheTanadu. As long as previous chainers don't changed the subject, you don't have to worry about multiple assertion by `.and()`. Your ESLint complains about: `.to.be.enabled`, as they are getters with side effects. Another approach for multiple assertion, even if it seems superfluous, is to wrap the yielded subject inside your callback on each assertion: `cy.get('button').then($button => { cy.wrap($button).should('be.enabled'); cy.wrap($button).click(); });`, or you can install this nice plugin in order to override a bit your rule:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-chai-friendly

Comment: @AlexIzbas well... that last one is the one I'm searching then... thanks!

Comment: @AlexIzbas that's the right approach - you should not have to modify valid Cypress code to pacify the linter.